# Magento File/Image Upload on Front Product View

Tags: php, magento, file-upload, image-upload

I want to add file uploader on front product view of product. here are some simple steps which describe its working.

currently page loads with a big product image which has 4-6 image map points.

on each map when user click on it, a popup needs to be display asking user to upload file for that mapped area.

Comment: Please specify what you want exactly?

Comment: when user clicks on any image map at magento front product page, a popup with file upload option needs to be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a product option or what?

Somwhere on product page you have hidden divs with product upload forms. You click map points and divs appear with help of JS.

Comment: this is what i am asking. i need some code snippet.. i am new to magento.